# Laptop turns off after connecting adapter

Tags: laptop-repair, charging, ac-adapter

I have an HP ProBook 4520s. When I connect AC adapter to it, it turns off immediately and I cant turn it on again for about 20 minutes. Charging LED doesn't turn on. Adapter voltage looks normal. What could be the problem?

Comment: I would first suggest you to try with another power adapter. If the other adapter  also exhibits the same behavior, then replace the DC port. If nothing works, I would suspect a faulty motherboard.

Comment: Refer to [this post](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Hardware-and-Upgrade-Questions/Laptop-shuts-down-when-Ac-adapter-is-plugged-in/m-p/6417320/highlight/true#M426856)

Comment: "Adapter voltage looks normal" Did you measure it under correct load, or just test the voltage at the pins?

Comment: @Tetsujin No. Just pins. However there shouldn't be much difference between free and under load voltage. I'll test with another adapter if I can find another one with same voltage and plug head. The strange thing is it takes long time (20m~2h) to be able to turn it on again after shutting down by plugging in adapter.

Comment: Open it might push 20v, under load it might only push 3v. Unless you can test it loaded, you haven't tested it.

Comment: @Tetsujin You are right but such problems are usually caused by overload, not underload. Some time ago, adapter of my laptop (Acer Aspire E1-572G) produced lower voltage than required and my laptop responded by blinking battery LED; not turning off and denying turn on button for long time. Behavior of this HP laptop is like a [PPTC fuse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resettable_fuse).